# MonoDevelop: error VBNC99999

Tags: mono

hope someone is using Mono & monodevelop...
 i'm getting the following error when i try to compile an ASP.NET apps ported from vs.net 2008

Error VBNC99999: Unexpected error: The classes in the module cannot be loaded. (VBNC99999)

This is the only error i get. 
I'm using 4 external assembly / dll

AjaxControlToolkit.dll
FusionCharts.dll
MySql.Data.dll
PostBackRitalin.dll

I've added the dll in bin directory, then i've referenced it.

I'm using Mono, because on my "old" computer (acer aspire t2300 buyed in 2007) run with linux & with monodevelop very well.
With windows, visual studio is reeeeeeally slow.. so i decide to pass to mono..

Can somenone know something about that error ?

Thank you very much. Regards !

Answer (score 0):

I can guess a few possible reasons, though it's hard to be sure without more info.

- The Mono VB.NET compiler is only a VB8 compiler (VS2005), so if you're using VB9 features that might explain the problem.
- One of the libraries you're using might be a mixed-mode binary, and contain native Windows code.
- You might have found a bug in the VB compiler. If you think this is the case, you should file a bug report.

Beware that Mono's VB.NET compiler is nowhere near as actively developed and tested as the C# one, and MonoDevelop doesn't have code completion or refactoring for VB either. I generally recommend that VB devs compile on Windows and copy the binaries over to Linux, or learn C#...